# Asking for CMS & its website architecture design using the same MySQL database

Tags: java, database-design, architecture, database-replication, messagebroker

CMS and its website use the same MySql database instance (e.g. CMS editor can create, edit website user which will be reflected on a user table, on the other hand, user can be created too when a user wants to register on the website, edit his/her information and so on). So I want to understand the best architecture design to use it in this system to make it more scalable without database locks when writing from both apps simultaneously. Is there a need for a message broker from the 2nd app or another database instance? what's the best or there is another better solution?

Comment: This question is [cross-posted](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/393543/asking-for-cms-its-website-architecture-design-using-the-same-mysql-database). It is also overly broad and opinionated:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Rob I've removed it from the other side. Thanks!